# Why both inline and hot flag required in webpack-dev-server to enable hot reloading

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

In [every documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#hot-module-replacement-with-inline-mode-on-cli) or article I see to enable HMR with webpack-dev-server we need to use `webpack-dev-server --hot --inline`, Interestingly even if I omit `hot` flag and only keep `inline` in my code-base HMR still works. Is all the documentations are old or I'm doing wrong ?

I'm not defining any `devServer` option in my webpack config ,here's my web-pack config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
     main: "./app/main.ts",
     shims: ['es6-shim', 'reflect-metadata', 'rxjs', 'zone.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "./dist/[name].js",
        sourceMapFilename: "./dist/[name].map"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "#source-map"
};
```

Here is my `package.json` script

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && webpack-dev-server --inline --port 9876",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
```

Here's the [entire code](https://github.com/Ng2book/angular2-webpack-starter-kit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use it without `--hot`, it will force a full refresh (no HMR)

For example the style loader implements the HMR interface and is able to patch style changes without forcing a full refresh.

Comment: what if I just use ` --inline --hot` without any `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin` , is that same as same as `--inline` ? cause with or without `--hot` I dont see any behavioral difference in my App

Comment: If I remember right, this depends. Through the CLI it injects `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` but if you set up `devServer`, then it doesn't. I'll change that.